# issue with accordian Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote accordion script to deploy in mobile website, every thing is working fine. However I am facing one issue when the page length is increasing.

there are about 8 to 10 bars in accordion. when i am scrolling down and clicking any of the item bar to display content, page is moving to top instead of staying at current position where i have clicked.

Please advice me the solution.

below is the script

$('.acc_container').hide(); 
 $('.acc_container1').hide();

$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.acc_container1').slideUp('fast');
  $(this).parent().siblings('div').children('.acc_container1').slideUp('fast');
  $(this).parent().siblings('div').children('.acc_container').slideUp('fast');
  $(this).next().siblings('.acc_container').slideDown('fast');
 });

Comment: is your click a href , please post the code , if it is href you have to had preventDefault....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each of your accordion's triggers which display content, which I assume are anchor tags, you need to prevent the default behavior of the event. Which in the case of anchor tags, is to take you too the `href` attribute of the tag. If the `href` attribute is set to `#`, clicking on the anchor tag will take you to the top of the page. So, something like this should work, calling `preventDefault()` on jQuery's `event` object, assuming `.acc_trigger` is the selector for all of your accordian triggers:

```
$(".acc_trigger").click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.acc_container1').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).parent().siblings('div').children('.acc_container1').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).parent().siblings('div').children('.acc_container').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().siblings('.acc_container').slideDown('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your click might a href click if so

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
// do all your logic here and add the below link  

event.preventDefault();

});
```

If that is not href

Give your .acc_container class a set height of you need like 500px  or so,  and an

```
height:600px;
overflow: hidden;
```

That should take carek